# No puedo usar file_get_contents en PHP con la API de Instagram

Tags: php, instagram-api

Necesito obtener algunos datos que facilita Instagram gracias a su API. Visitando la [este enlace](https://www.instagram.com/NASA/?__a=1), podemos obtener los datos del perfil de la NASA (como ejemplo), y con [este otro](https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=NASA), podemos obtener una lista de perfiles en instagram, con varios datos de cada uno.

El problema, es que usando [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) de PHP devuelve "false" con el primero (1) y es correcto con el segundo (2). Estas son las URL:

1: `https://www.instagram.com/NASA/?__a=1`

2: `https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=NASA`

**Código usado** (con ambos, cambiando solo la URL)

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/NASA/?__a=1");
$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response); // Devuelve: NULL
```

Estoy obteniendo los mismos resultados que quiero con el segundo, pero por algún motivo, tarda 9-11 segundos en devolver el resultado, ya sea con PHP o acceso directo al enlace.

Si es cosa de instagram y no se puede hacer nada, ¿Cómo puedo obtener el resultado de la segunda URL más rápido? (si es posible)

Comment: Prueba con [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700960/how-to-use-curl-to-get-json-data-and-decode-the-data)

Comment: @BlackSheep Tampoco, he encontrado en un foro que Instagram bloquea el acceso a esa URL mediante el servidor o algo así, y he encontrado otro método de hacerlo. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

> Instagram ha bloqueado de alguna manera el acceso a los datos de las
>   cuentas mediante esa URL.

**Hay otra forma de hacerlo:**

```
$username = "NASA";

$url = "https://www.instagram.com/".$username;
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$arr = explode('window._sharedData = ',$html);
$arr = explode(';</script>',$arr[1]);
$obj = json_decode($arr[0] , true);

var_dump($obj);
```

Sigue siendo igual de lenta que usando la API de búsqueda (segundo enlace) pero al menos obtienes los datos de una sola cuenta y es correcta, ya que con la búsqueda a veces el primer resultado no es la cuenta sobre la que quieres los datos.